# How to use protractor to check if an element is visible?

Tags: angularjs, visible, protractor

I'm trying to test if an element is visible using protractor. Here's what the element looks like:

```
<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin ng-hide" ng-show="saving"></i>
```

When in the chrome console, I can use this jQuery selector to test if the element is visible:

```
$('[ng-show=saving].icon-spin')
[
<i class=​"icon-spinner icon-spin ng-hide" ng-show=​"saving">​</i>​
]
> $('[ng-show=saving].icon-spin:visible')
[]
```

However, when I try to do the same in protractor, I get this error at runtime:

```
InvalidElementStateError: 
invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 
'[ng-show=saving].icon-spin:visible' is not a valid selector.
```

Why is this not valid? How can I check for visibility using protractor?

Comment: @limp_chimp for such things as visibility, think about using AngularJS client DOM unit tests. They are much faster to run and easier to develop.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This should do it:

```
expect($('[ng-show=saving].icon-spin').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Remember protractor's `$` isn't jQuery and `:visible` is not *yet* a part of [available CSS selectors + pseudo-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

More info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388700/511069

Comment: The answer below also uses `isDisplayed()` but just expands to resolve the promise for completeness though that step is optional and only meant for including conditionals in your tests which is a bad practice. @asenovm can you further elaborate your "This is plain wrong" comment?

Comment: @LeoGallucci, isDisplayed() returns ElementFinder and not a boolean.

Comment: Please don't use `.toBeTruthy();` use `.toBe(true)` instead. `.toBeTruthy();` will match things like [], 'false', 42. Basically anything expect 0, "", null, undefined, NaN or false is truthy.

Answer (score 78):

The correct way for checking the visibility of an element with Protractor is to call the [**`isDisplayed`**](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#webdriverwebelementprototypeisdisplayed) method. You should be careful though since `isDisplayed` does not return a boolean, but rather a **`promise`** providing the evaluated visibility. I've seen lots of code examples that use this method wrongly and therefore don't evaluate its actual visibility.

Example for getting the visibility of an element:

```
element(by.className('your-class-name')).isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
        // element is visible
    } else {
        // element is not visible
    }
});
```

However, you don't need this if you are just checking the visibility of the element (as opposed to getting it) because protractor patches Jasmine expect() so it always waits for promises to be resolved. See [github.com/angular/jasminewd](http://github.com/angular/jasminewd)

So you can just do:

```
expect(element(by.className('your-class-name')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Since you're using `AngularJS` to control the visibility of that element, you could also check its class attribute for `ng-hide` like this:

```
var spinner = element.by.css('i.icon-spin');
expect(spinner.getAttribute('class')).not.toMatch('ng-hide'); // expect element to be visible
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue, in that I only wanted return elements that were visible in a page object. I found that I'm able to use the css `:not`. In the case of this issue, this should do you...

```
expect($('i.icon-spinner:not(.ng-hide)').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

In the context of a page object, you can get ONLY those elements that are visible in this way as well. Eg. given a page with multiple items, where only some are visible, you can use:

```
this.visibileIcons = $$('i.icon:not(.ng-hide)');
```

This will return you all visible `i.icon`s

Comment: isDisplayed() should be in the expect scope as @leoGallucci explained it.

Answer (score 5):

If there are multiple elements in DOM with same class name. But only one of element is visible.

```
element.all(by.css('.text-input-input')).filter(function(ele){
        return ele.isDisplayed();
    }).then(function(filteredElement){
        filteredElement[0].click();
    });
```

In this example filter takes a collection of elements and returns a single visible element using **isDisplayed()**.

Comment: This is a great answer; consider the case where there is no such element! $('.text-input-input') would alert the user elegantly; this might fail because `filteredElement.length === 0`?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will be robust enough to work for elements that aren't on the page, therefore failing gracefully (not throwing an exception) if the selector failed to find the element.

```
const nameSelector = '[data-automation="name-input"]';
const nameInputIsDisplayed = () => {
    return $$(nameSelector).count()
        .then(count => count !== 0)
}
it('should be displayed', () => {
    nameInputIsDisplayed().then(isDisplayed => {
        expect(isDisplayed).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To wait for visibility

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('.icon-spinner icon-spin ng-hide')))).then(function() {
  //do stuff
})
```

Xpath trick to only find visible elements

```
element(by.xpath('//i[not(contains(@style,"display:none")) and @class="icon-spinner icon-spin ng-hide"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element(by.className('your-class-name'))
  .isDisplayed()
  .then(function (isVisible) {
     if (isVisible) { // element is visible
     } else {         // element is not visible
     }
  })
  .catch(function(err){
     console.error("Element is not found! ", err);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few code snippet which can be used for framework which use Typescript, protractor, jasmine

```
browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(OversightAutomationOR.lblContentModal), 3000, "Modal text is present");
```

// Asserting a text

```
OversightAutomationOR.lblContentModal.getText().then(text => {
                    this.assertEquals(text.toString().trim(), AdminPanelData.lblContentModal);
                });
```

// Asserting an element

```
expect(OnboardingFormsOR.masterFormActionCloneBtn.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.equal(true

    );

OnboardingFormsOR.customFormActionViewBtn.isDisplayed().then((isDisplayed) => {
                        expect(isDisplayed).to.equal(true);
                });
```

// Asserting a form

```
formInfoSection.getText().then((text) => {
                        const vendorInformationCount = text[0].split("\n");
                        let found = false;
                        for (let i = 0; i < vendorInformationCount.length; i++) {
                            if (vendorInformationCount[i] === customLabel) {
                                found = true;
                            };
                        };
                        expect(found).to.equal(true);
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

### Something to consider

`.isDisplayed()` assumes the element is present (exists in the DOM)

so if you do

```
expect($('[ng-show=saving]').isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

but the element is not present, then instead of graceful failed expectation, `$('[ng-show=saving]').isDisplayed()` will throw an error causing the rest of `it` block not executed

### Solution

If you assume, the element you're checking may not be present for any reason on the page, then go with a safe way below

```
/**
*  element is Present and is Displayed
*  @param    {ElementFinder}      $element       Locator of element
*  @return   {boolean}
*/
let isDisplayed = function ($element) {
  return (await $element.isPresent()) && (await $element.isDisplayed())
}
```

and use

```
expect(await isDisplayed( $('[ng-show=saving]') )).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
waitTillElementIsPresent(locator: Locator): promise.Promise<boolean> 
{

const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id('xyz')), browser.params.explicitWaitTime, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const isDisplayed = await $('div').isDisplayed().then(null, err => false)
```