# Protractor isPresent() result for elements in/with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In my application I have a controller who's scope has a model that is used for determining a condition in my view. Very standard.

*Controller*

```
$scope.shouldShow = false;
$scope.seeCoal = true;
```

*View*

```
<div ng-controller="SomeController" ng-if="shouldShow">
  <span id="coal" ng-show="seeCoal"></span>
</div>
```

Fair enough. When I change this `shouldShow` to something truthy, then this div will render.

How will protractor interpret this and it's contained markup? If my test does *not* set the `shouldShow` model to true, then will the `#coal` element be considered to be present by `element.isPresent()`?

Also, if (in my test) I do *not* set `shouldShow` to truthy (keep it false), and set `seeCoal` to false - will I be able to traverse to `#coal` to confirm that the `ng-hide` class is present, even though it's parent has an `ng-if` condition that evaluates to false?

In my project where I'm trying this out, I have too many uncertainties and I can't be sure as to how protractor is supposed to work in these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular's `ng-if` will remove its impacted elements from the DOM. So, they and their sub elements will not be visible in any form to Protractor. If `shouldShow` is falsey the “coal” span will not be visible to Protractor at all.

The `ng-show` leaves an element in the DOM but makes it invisible. See [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide).

A Protractor locator should be able to find an `ng-show`-hidden element. The `isDisplayed()` method on its promise should promise to return false.  See [How to use protractor to check if an element is visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850271/how-to-use-protractor-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible)