# Protractor isDisplayed() method is failing with Timeout Error

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, cucumber

Protractor `isDisplayed()` method is failing with `Timeout Error` when object is not displayed on the page.
Same issue exists with `isPresent()`.

Below is the code snippet:

```
public async checkifelementisdisplayed(webElmntXpath: string) {
    let webElement = (element(by.xpath(webElmntXpath)));

    try {`enter code here`
         const eleStat = await webElement.isDisplayed(); //Tried with isPresent() as well
         console.log("element status is "+eleStat);

         if (eleStat) {
              return true;
         }
         else {
              return false;
         }
     } catch (e) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

> Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 60000
> milliseconds
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\UIAutomation\node_modules\cucumber\lib\user_code_runner.js:76:18)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if your page

1. is angular
2. is protractor ready

See these answers how to check https://stackoverflow.com/a/66111219/9150146

And a 1 min read answer about proper usage of `isDisplayed` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110622/9150146

Answer (score -1):

Try adding await keyword for below line
let webElement = await element(by.xpath(webElmntXpath));

Comment: Still getting same error after adding await

Comment: IsPresent() does not throw any error if element is not present. Hope the element which you are looking for is not inside a frame. Try with explicit wait as well

Comment: element is not a promise and thus doesn't require `await`

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov, You are right.. No need of await before element.

Comment: @Sreeresh same code is working when webelement is displayed, and there is no  frame.

Comment: So you have increased explicit wait duration?

Comment: If the web element is not found with in the given time duration, it should return false but it is failing with timeout error.